# How do I rename relationships in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, rename, relationship, keyword, cypher

I realized only after importing a ton of nodes that I had created relationships called `START`, which is a reserved keyword. Querying the DB through the Cypher console hence always complains about the reserved keywords:

> SyntaxException: reserved keyword "start n=node(0) match n<-[:START]-r
>   return count(r)"

The only workaround that comes to mind is creating new copy relationships with a different name and then deleting the old ones.

Is there an easy way to rename all of these relationships or some way to escape reserved keywords in Cypher?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. You cannot rename an already existing relationship. You'd have to [run through all relationships](http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/tooling/GlobalGraphOperations.html#getAllRelationships%28%29), create the new one in parallel (including all properties) and then remove the old one.

You may also want to consider quoting the reserved word `START` in your cypher queries with backticks and leave the relationships as they are:

```
start n=node(0) match n<-[:`START`]-r return count(r)
```

Comment: I want to keep same relationship ID to the newly added relationship. How could I?

Answer (score 34):

To do the equivalent of a rename, you can create a new one and delete the old one like so:

```
match (n1)-[old:`Start`]->(n2)
create (n1)-[new:StartDate]->(n2)
delete old
```

n.b. use backticks like those around `Start` to escape reserved keywords

Comment: Best answer for Neo4j 2.x, note also that you can replace the "create" with "merge" if you want to avoid having duplicates if executing again.

Comment: this approach won't keep the properties of previous relation

Answer (score 6):

You can use [apoc](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/rename-label-type-property/) plugin to rename labels and relationships.
You can also use this to select a subset of relationships to rename. For eg below query will rename only relationship between Jim and Alistair.

```
MATCH (:Engineer {name: "Jim"})-[rel]->(:Engineer {name: "Alistair"})
WITH collect(rel) AS rels
CALL apoc.refactor.rename.type("COLLEAGUES", "FROLLEAGUES", rels)
YIELD committedOperations
RETURN committedOperations
```

Answer (score 2):

```
match (n1)-[old:`Start`]->(n2)
create (n1)-[new:StartDate {propName:old.propName, ...}]->(n2)
delete old
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22085663)